# How to edit CSS of "fine uploader" widget in Contao CMS?

Tags: css, module, widget, content-management-system, contao

I have spent many hours to search of how can I modify the fineUploader package from here https://packagist.org/packages/terminal42/contao-fineuploader . Is there any way of how can I modify the CSS of that package? I want to match it with the rest of the contact form.

Also the support and the forums are all in German language and they say nothing about the customisation of that package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the stylesheet [here](https://github.com/terminal42/contao-fineuploader/blob/main/src/Resources/public/frontend/frontend.css). And in your contao installation you can find it in the vendor folder

> /root/vendor/terminal42/contao-fineuploader/src/Resources/public/frontend

You could look up all the selectors there but if you overwrite them there, all your changes will be gone after an update. So usualy you just overwrite them in a new e.g. 'my_styles.css' which you include directly in your fe_page.html5 or in your Layout.